# React native List View onEndReached calling multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am facing some trouble using the List View onEndReached component in react native.

Render code:

```
@autobind
  _fetchMoreHistory(){

    console.log("Fetch more history called");

  }

<View style={[styles.Ctr]}>
   <ListView dataSource={this.state.txHistorySource}
         renderRow={ this._renderRow }
         onEndReached ={ this._fetchMoreHistory }
         onEndReachedThreshold  = {10}/>
</View>
```

The moment I open the screen `_fetchMoreHistory` is called twice and works normally after that `onEndReached` reached. Can someone help debug this ?

Comment: How many rows are you fetching? *onEndReached* is executed at the end of the rendering of the rows, so you set the limit to **10**, I think you have just more thant 10 rows. It's possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FlatList calls \`onEndReached\` when it's rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910127/flatlist-calls-onendreached-when-its-rendered)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. But I figured out that I had the `ScrollView` that wraps my `FlatList`. 
When I removed it all started working properly.

It's a pity that **NOTHING WAS SAID ABOUT THAT IN THE OFFICIAL DOCS**

Comment: this should be correct answer for those who wrapped flatlist in scrollView

Comment: This is correct answer +1

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue and searched a lot but didn't find any answers, so I used a condition to check if the first request got the data I fire onendreashed again else I don't

Example
// onEndReached
If(condition) {
Make the call 
}

Answer (score 4):

So my solution is simple. Don't use `onEndReached` at all. Use `onScroll` and detect the end of the scroll.

`isCloseToBottom = ({ layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize }) => {
    const paddingToBottom = 20; // how far from the bottom
    return layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >= 
    contentSize.height - paddingToBottom;
  };`

and the `FlatList` component

```
 <FlatList      
      data={data}        
       onScroll={({ nativeEvent }) => {
          if (this.isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)) {
            // Dont forget to debounce or throttle this function.
            this.handleOnEndReached();
          }
       }}
  />
```

Comment: Terrible approach. This will be called multiple times.

Comment: thats why I added a comment there (Dont forget to debounce or throttle this function.)

Comment: The comment doesn't change anything. This is not the way it's done.

Answer (score 2):

You can try my solution

1. You should configure limit > 10. Example limit = 15
2. Add onMomentumScrollBegin prop to your ListView declaration.

   ```
   <ListView
     data={this.props.data}
     onEndReached={...}
     onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
     ...
     onMomentumScrollBegin={() => { this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = false; }}
   />
   ```
3. Modify your onEndReached callback to trigger data fetching only once per momentum.

   `onEndReached =()=> {
       if(!this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum) {
         this.props.fetchData();
         this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = true;
       }
   };`

Comment: onMomentumScrollBegin doesn't seem to be a property of FlatList: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html

Comment: @Broonix : may be it is removed in newest version. You can find another properties

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this problem by creating a state variable that tells me is the service is loading or not.

```
class Component1 extends Component {
public constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        isLoading: false,
        listOfItems: []
    };
}

public componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
}

public render(){
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={this.state.listOfItems}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
            onEndReached={this.loadData}
        />
    );
}

private loadData = () => {
    if (this.state.isLoading === true) {
        /// Avoid make another request is there's happening a request right now
        return;
    }

    this.setState({isLoading: true});

    this.fetchData()
        .then(() => {
        /// Handle success response
            this.setState({isLoading: false});
        })
        .catch(() => {
              this.setState({isLoading: false});
        });
}
```

}

Comment: How do you trigger isLoading to be "true" without skipping the first first load?

Comment: @user1230795 the best way to do that if in your componentDidMount method you explicitly call the load data. pd: I've updated my response in order to make the example more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the code for fetching data in `onMomentumScrollEnd` rather than `onEndReached`, like this:

```
onMomentumScrollEnd={() => this.props.onEndReached()}
```

It might not be written as the available prop in the react native documentation, but if you will see the source code for `FlatList`, it uses `Virtualized List` which in return has the mentioned prop available.