# FlatList calls `onEndReached` when it's rendered

Tags: react-native

Here is render() function for my simple `category list page`.

Recently I added pagination for my `FlatList` View so when the user scrolls to the bottom, `onEndReached` is called in a certain point(`onEndReachedThreshold` value length from the bottom), and it will fetch the next `categories` and concatenate the categories props.

But my problem is **onEndReached is called when render() is called** In other words, FlatList's `onEndReached` is triggered before it reach the bottom.

Am I putting wrong value for `onEndReachedThreshold?` Do you see any problem?

```
return (
  <View style={{ flex:1 }}>
    <FlatList
      data={this.props.categories}
      renderItem={this._renderItem}
      keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
      numColumns={2}
      style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}
      contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center'}}
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          refreshing = {this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh = {()=>this._onRefresh()}
        />
      }
      // curent value for debug is 0.5
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.5} // Tried 0, 0.01, 0.1, 0.7, 50, 100, 700

      onEndReached = {({distanceFromEnd})=>{ // problem
        console.log(distanceFromEnd) // 607, 878 
        console.log('reached'); // once, and if I scroll about 14% of the screen, 
                             //it prints reached AGAIN. 
        this._onEndReachedThreshold()
      }}
    />
  </View>
)
```

**UPDATE** I fetch `this.props.categories` data here

```
  componentWillMount() {
    if(this.props.token) {
      this.props.loadCategoryAll(this.props.token);
    }
  }
```

Comment: ```onEndReachedThreshold``` value range is 0 and 1, where 0 is the top of the scroll and 1 is the end of it. At first, I'd try adding 0.7 to it and check if it works as expected. Let me know if it helped

Comment: Thanks! But 0.7 didn't solve the problem. Still triggering onEndReached at the first time

Comment: what about having a class variable like this._mounted?

Comment: I'm fetching `categories` data from server using axios, react-redux. I send the ajax request on componenetWillMount but I assume I'm getting data after all the components were mounted.

Comment: having a class can be a possible solution but it's hard to find the exact time point when the categories are rendered

Comment: I was about to say something like this. If your content is rendered after your ```FlatList``` it may cause the scroll to change and then trigger your ```onEndReached``` as this post suggests https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12827#issuecomment-290461093 Try adding some console.log to check whether the content has finished or not when your FlatList first renders

Comment: If this is the case, you can try adding some conditional rendering to render your ```FlatList``` only after your ```categories``` is filled with values. Something like this: ```categories.length > 0 ? <FlatList... /> : < ActivityIndicator />```

Comment: @soutot Great Insight! I have `if` statement which check the length of the categories. It shows an image showing `No Category yet`. Um... any other idea? I can't think of it more

Comment: I updated the code on my question. please check :)

Comment: You can try adding this condition inside your ```<View>```. Something like this: ```<View> {categories ? <FlatList ... > : <Image ... /> } </View>```. You can find more examples here: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html Let me know if it works

Comment: It's exactly same with how I implemented `this.props.categories && this.props.categories.length==0`

Comment: sorry, were you able to solve it?

Comment: not yet. working on it

Comment: @JohnBaek have you tried my solution?

Comment: My problem was, I placed the FlatList inside ScrollView container. Maybe you have to make the FlatList independent to other View containers.

Comment: @soutot That is not how onEndReachedThreshold works at all: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

Comment: Im still having this problem even with these solutions. I just don't fucking understand why Facebook didn't fix this. Its a critical component for React Native

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Try to implement `onMomentumScrollBegin` on `FlatList` :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = true;
}
```

...

```
<FlatList
    ...
    onEndReached={this.onEndReached.bind(this)}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
    onMomentumScrollBegin={() => { this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = false; }}
/>
```

and modify your `onEndReached`

```
onEndReached = ({ distanceFromEnd }) => {
    if(!this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum){
        this.fetchData();
        this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Sorry I had serious techinical issue on other problem, and now I'm back to this problem :) I tried out your solution but it just stops `onEndReached` behavior. Also I'm not familiar with `constructor(props)` syntax, can we try out with `ES6` syntax? I kindda like your logic :)

Comment: @JohnBaek Hi! yes you can try also without constructor, just use state

Comment: state = { onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum : true }?

Comment: state = { onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum: true }
and onMomentum
this.setState({ onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum : false })

Comment: Interesting. onEndReached is triggered only one time

Comment: @JohnBaek so it works? :) In case can you accept my answer?

Comment: Sorry no it doesnt. It renders only the first page

Comment: @JohnBaek I don't understand.. onEndReached is called? Have you added this.setState({ onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum: true }) inside onEndReached?

Comment: Hi @llario i can confirm it called onEndReached once even with your solution i.e. this.setState({ onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum: true })

Comment: Using `onMomentumScrollBegin` only works if you **scroll gliding** _(ie. drag pull & let go)_... It doesn't register if you **drag slowly to the end** (without letting go).

Comment: Facing same issue. Tried your solution nut {onMomentumScrollBegin} is never being called!!!

Comment: intutive, is there a web version?

Comment: This did not work on web (react-native-web). The `onMomentumScrollBegin` never fires, i tried some other scrollview events but didn't work. Odd...

Comment: It looks like React Native stores a `hasDataChangedSinceEndReached` internal variable which it uses to not keep calling `onEndReached` a billion times once there's no more data to load. However, the downside is that if you use a conditional inside `onEndReached` to decide whether or not to call `fetchData`, the first time you *don't* load data, React Native figures there's no more data to load, so it won't call `onEndReached` ever again. tl;dr this doesn't work :(

Comment: I found maybe a way to fix this is to send `extraData` to the `FlatList` since that will cause `hasDataChangedSinceEndReached` to reset to `true`. I used just a random timestamp `new Date().getTime()` and seems to work. But only send this in if you're *not* going to call `fetchData` otherwise you'll break the magic of `FlatList` to not call `onEndReached` a billion times. tl;dr either change `data` or `extraData` inside the `onEndReached` and you'll get the behaviour you want.

Comment: it working using this way. remove my current `onEndReach` and `onEndReachThreshold` and follow `onEndReached = ({ distanceFromEnd }) => ...` with `onMomentumScrollBegin`. result as per expected.

Answer (score 37):

I've got it working with

```
<Flatlist
    ...
    onEndReached={({ distanceFromEnd }) => {
        if (distanceFromEnd < 0) return;
        ...
    }
    ...
/>
```

Comment: Could you explain this solution, it works for me at least. The distance count upward or downward the screen ?

Answer (score 35):

First check if the FlatList is inside a `ScrollView` or `Content` of native-base. Then take it outside of it
Actually you don't need to use `Content` or `ScrollView`, as FlatList has both `ListFooterComponent` and `ListHeaderComponent`.

Though it is not recommended, if you really need to use Flatlist inside ScrollView, then take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57603742/6170191

Comment: Yes, My FlatList is inside scrollview and the issue is gone after I remove it

Comment: @Nagibaba - Where can i find other recommendations and best practices for Flatlist and react native in general ?
I read briefly through https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance but did not find any mention of not using flatList inside scroll view. But then again I haven't read through entire react native docs, so a link to a particular page would be helpful.

Comment: Dear @sushrut619 react native has many bottlenecks that affects performance highly. Don't read whole docs. Searching Google about `react-native performance` will give you a brighter look at many processes, but there are still many issues you may find in the future. Then stackoverflow and github will help you)

Comment: What about a classic View? I need to put an absolute positioned element on the page to be always available. - btw, even if I put the `FlatList` as the top component in the screen, `onEndReached` is still called on first render, sometimes on second

Answer (score 16):

After hours of trying different approaches I got it to work by wrapping the Flatlist with a View of fixed height and flex:1.
With this settings, I was able to get onEndReached called once and only after I scroll near the bottom. Here's my code sample:

```
render() {
    const {height} = Dimensions.get('window');
    return (    
        <View style={{flex:1, height:height}}>
            <FlatList
                data={this.props.trips_uniques}
                refreshing={this.props.tripsLoading}
                onRefresh={()=> this.props.getTripsWatcher()}
                onEndReached={()=>this.props.getMoreTripsWatcher()}
                onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                renderItem={({item}) => (
                <View style={Style.card}> 
                    ...
                    ...
                </View>
                )}
                keyExtractor={item => item.trip_id}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

My onEndReached() function just calls the API and updates my data. It doesn't do any calculations with regards to distance to bottom or threshold

Comment: Perfect solution.

Comment: If you got down here ... please check you have `onEndReachedThreshold` set, docs sound like it has some reasonable default, it doesn't, start with `onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}` ...

Comment: Like a charm. Saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 9):

Most of the times, this error is caused because of an incorrect use of onEndReachedThreashold, which also depends of the number of items you are rendering (more items, more scroll size).

Try to follow this logic:

If 10 items cover your screen, and you are rendering 20 items on each scroll, then set onEndReachedThreashold to 0.8.

If 2 or 3 items cover your screen, and you are rendering 10 items on each scroll, then set onEndReachedThreashold to 0.5.

Also, use initialNumToRender = numItems. For some reason, using this FlatList prop helps to reduce the chance of multiple onEndReached calls.

Just play with onEndReachedThreashold value.

---

Other times, this error is produced because of nesting scroll views. Do not put your FlatList inside of a ScrollView. Instead, take use of the FlatList header and footer props.

---

For both solutions, I suggest to set the FlatList style and contentContainerStyle to { [flexGrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow): 1 }.

Answer (score 3):

Remove every **Scrollable** View inside your FlatList

Answer (score 3):

A bit late but I just ran into this issue and I fixed it by passing to my `<FlatList/>` the [initialNumToRender](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#initialnumtorender) prop. This prop is 10 by default so if you don't set it and your screen shows more than 10 items on the initial render, it is going to trigger `onEndReached` since it has passed the 10th element.

`initialNumToRender` should probably be the same as the amount of elements you fetch per page.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show 3 or 4 records and want to load the next data just when you reach the end. Set onEndReachedThreshold to 0 or 0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe You can bypass this FlatList bug by incrementing your **page** before doing async call, and then you will fetch data on every onEndReached fiers and not get errors about duplicate keys

Answer (score 1):

**(as of NOV19)**

1. Keep flatlist as the only component inside of a single view
2. Set style of that single view from dimensions like
   `{{flex: 1, height: Dimensions.get('window').height}}`

Answer (score 1):

If FlatList is on another FlatList or ScrollView the onEndReached call immediately when rendered component to resolve that problem doesn't wrap FlatList with another.

Answer (score 1):

Since I haven't specifically seen this case here: If you render FlatList with an empty data source and add onEndReached to it, it will fire the onEndReached no matter the Threshold.

It seems it then disables the onEndReached completely as a safety measure even if there are items added to the data source later on.

My fix was to not render the FlatList with an empty data set, which I probably should've done to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I have a `<FlatList>` (from react-native) inside an `<Overlay>` (from react-native-elements.) I have the problem of `onEndReached` being executed as soon as the component is rendered for the 1st time and before the user does anything.

The problem was resolved by using `<Modal>` (from react-native), instead of `<Overlay>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hooks, here you can find the hook version of @Ilario answer:

```js
const onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = useRef(true)

onEndReachedHandler = ({ distanceFromEnd }) => {
    if(!onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum.current){
        fetchData()
        onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum.current = true
    }
}

<FlatList
    ...
    onEndReached={onEndReachedHandler}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.7}
    onMomentumScrollBegin={() => { onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum.current = false }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple solution worked for me.  Note the "refreshing" state is controlled by an async API call in a useEffect hook to retrieve data for the FlatList.

```
const onEndReachedHandler = () => {
    if (!refreshing) ...
}

<FlatList
    ...
    data={mydata}
    onEndReached={onEndReachedHandler}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.7}
    refreshing={refreshing}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled around the whole day but the issue that I was getting is, I am using FlatList inside ScrollView. So, Remove Scrollview & then use Flatlist independently. This will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you can simply utilize **onEndReachedThreshold** props in your FlatList or SectionList and pass a very very small number like 0.001 to it.

```
onEndReachedThreshold={0.001}
```

According to [docs for FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onendreachedthreshold), onEndReachedThreshold is units of length from the bottom in list items.

> How far from the end (in units of visible length of the list) the
> bottom edge of the list must be from the end of the content to trigger
> the onEndReached callback. For example, a value of 0.5 will trigger
> onEndReached when the end of the content is within half the visible
> length of the list.

Thus, a very small value like 0.001 helps you to make sure that onEndReached is only gonna be called when the end of the content is within the very end of the visible length of the list.

Hope this helps :) Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simpler than anyone would think.

Just add an !isLoading condition for fetch calling. It works for me:

```
 onEndReached={() => {
      if (!isLoading) {
        fetchProducts();
      }
 }}
```

And the full code with ScrollView and FlatList:

```
<ScrollView
          horizontal={true}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          style={styles.mainContainer}>
          <FlatList
            ListHeaderComponent={TableHeader}
            data={displayedProducts}
            renderItem={(item: ListRenderItemInfo<IProduct>) => TableRow(item, showDeleteModal)}
            keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
            ListFooterComponent={<Loading loadingText={'Loading products...'} />}
            onEndReached={() => {
              if (!isLoading) {
                fetchProducts();
              }
            }}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.8}
            stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
          />
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onScroll` prop for determining when the scroller reaches a certain number of pixels from the bottom of the list

```js
onScroll={({ nativeEvent }) => {
    const { contentOffset, contentSize, layoutMeasurement } = nativeEvent;
    const numberOfPixelsFromBottomThreshold = 100;
    const isNearBottom = contentOffset.y + layoutMeasurement.height >= contentSize.height - numberOfPixelsFromBottomThreshold
    if (isNearBottom) {
        console.log('reached 100 pixels from the bottom of scrollview')
        console.log('run your custom onEndReached logic here')
        fetchMore?.(); // I usually fetchMore when end is reached
    }
}}
```

This method works `universally` for:

- ScrollView
- FlatList
- FlashList
- SectionList
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

For me (react native web in this case) it was to set a specific height directly on the flatlist style

```
            <FlatList
                style={{ height: windowDimensions.height }}
            // ...
```

Afterwards, `onScroll` and `onEndReached` worked correctly

Answer (score -6):

I have solved it with using debounce from lodash. Firstly, I import debounce from 'lodash.debounce'. Then I use debounce for load more function with 500 ms interval

`<Flatlist
 onEndReached = {debounce(this._onLoadMore, 500)}
/>`

Comment: Why do we want to implement with lodash, when the flatlist has all the functions defined? Why is react native not fixing these simple issues.

Comment: though I'm a fan of debounce, this solution does not work. The list will simply invoke the callback after the debounce interval. We need an onEndReach that only runs when the user reaches the end of the list.