# React Native FlatList inside ScrollView onEndReached never called

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

My container is a scrollview and inside it is a flatlist, which load data from server.

The flatlist:

```
<VirtualizedList
  ListEmptyComponent={<NoData />}
  data={data}
  getItem={(items, index) => items.get(index)}
  getItemCount={(items) => items.size}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
  renderItem={this._renderItem}
  refreshControl={
     <RefreshControl
       refreshing={loading}
       onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
     />
  }
  onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
  onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
  onMomentumScrollBegin={() => {
    Log('onMomentumScrollBegin fired!')
    this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = false;
  }}
/>
```

which `handleLoadMore` is:

```
handleLoadMore = () => {
  Log('handleLoadMore fired!');
  if (!this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum) {
    // fetch data..
    this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = true;
  }
}
```

The problem is the `handleLoadMore` never called and the `onMomentumScrollBegin` also never called.

How to solve this?

Comment: you used VirtualizedList or FlatList ??

Comment: VirtualizedList ..

Comment: please add this to debug your code ;) 
onEndReached={({ distanceFromEnd }) => {
                console.log('on end reached ', distanceFromEnd);
            }}

Comment: it never called onEndReached.. so no log out

Comment: @FaiChou did you try to increase `onEndReachedThreshold `? You can set it to 10 for example.

Comment: @FaiChou just one more thing, having a flat list inside a scrollview is not recommended at all. My guess is that this is where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 7):

Actually you don't need to use `Content` or `ScrollView` as FlatList has both `ListFooterComponent` and `ListHeaderComponent`

In case you really need to use FlatList inside `ScrollView`, then add style and content contentContainerStyle to your `ScrollView` or if you use native-base, inside the `Content`

```
<ScrollView
  ...
  style={{flex: 1}}
  contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}
  ...
/>
```

Then if you want to use header component out of FlatList loop. Then use `ListHeaderComponent={() => <SomeHeader />` inside Flatlist.