# How to implement onEndReached() and onRefresh() "horizontally" in react native FlatList in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

In my app I have a horizontal `flatlist` which rendering list of simple boxes horizontally like slide.

Here is my flatlist :

```js
<FlatList
    data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}, {key: 'c'}, {key: 'd'}, {key: 'e'}]}
    ref={(slider) => { this.slider = slider }}
    onEndReachedThreshold={1}
    onEndReached={() => {
        alert("onEndReached");
    }}
    refreshing={true}
    onRefresh={() => {
        alert("refreshing");
    }}
    renderItem={({item, index}) => (
        <View style={{
            paddingHorizontal: 5, 
            paddingVertical: 10,
        }}>
            <SlideItem><MText> Text {index} </MText></SlideItem>
        </View>
    )}
    horizontal={true}
/>
```

Now, I want to call some method when list reached the end. So I implemented `onEndReached()`. But it called at start when I scroll not when I reached at the end of list.

Basically my main aim is to load more data on right side when user reached at end of flatlist and load more data on left side when user reach on the first item of flatlist.

Please any one can help me !!!

Comment: I think it is similar with your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910127/flatlist-calls-onendreached-when-its-rendered

Comment: @bkm412 no, my problem is in horizontal flatlist.

Comment: @KishanBharda Facing the same issue. Did you find any fix ?

Comment: No, I have not found any solution @SrinivasDamam. I just replace it with https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel