# How to apply onEndReached in Flatlist?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I have a Flatlist that displays cards and information in it, I have to apply pagination to it i.e at first only 3 cards should load on reaching end more 3 cards should load.

Below is my code :

```
<FlatList
    style={{ height: HEIGHT, flex: 1 }}      // declared a HEIGHT const with value of windows height
    data={this.state.show_data_list}         // data to be shown in flatlist
    keyExtractor={(x, i) => x + i}  
    extraData={this.state.refresh}           // to sort the data based on condition.
    initialNumToRender={3}                   // data to be loaded initially
    onEndReached={() => this.loadMoreData()} // function which add 3 more items to show_data_list state to be shown in flatlist
    onEndReachedThreshold={10}
    renderItem={({ item }) =>
              <ContentCard
                  // content to display
              />
            }
         />
```

As soon as the view renders all data is shown, in other words, onEndReached is called before I reach at the end.
Can any of u guys know why this is happening ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `onMomentumScrollBegin` or check the distance from the end

```
    onEndReached={({ distanceFromEnd }) => {
            if (distanceFromEnd < 0) return; 
   }
```

Please refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910127/flatlist-calls-onendreached-when-its-rendered)