# React Native FlatList re-renders the already rendered items when adding new data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have implemented a code that listen my DB documents and when a new one is added the app renders it as an item on my FlatList.

The problem I have is that everytime I update the data of the FlatList, the already rendered items re-renders again and again...

As my original code is complex, I have build a Snack:
https://snack.expo.io/@victoriomolina/flatlist-re-renders-all-components

I think the problem is that I update the state using a shallow copy of the existing array, but I do it just to re-render the FlatList when new items are added *(I don't want to re-render the already rendered items)*.

Thank you, I will really appreciate your help.

Pd: In my original code the components of the FlatList extends React.PureComponent

### My Real Code

The fething part

```
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { firebase } = props;

    let postsArray = [];

    // Realtime database listener
    const unsuscribe = firebase
      .getDatabase()
      .collection("posts")
      .doc(firebase.getCurrentUser().uid)
      .collection("userPosts")
      .orderBy("date") // Sorted by upload date
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        let changes = snapshot.docChanges();

        changes.forEach((change) => {
          if (change.type === "added") {
            // Get the new post
            const newPost = change.doc.data();

            // Add the new post to the posts list
            postsArray.unshift(newPost);
          }
        });

        // Reversed order so that the last post is at the top of the list
        setPosts([...postsArray]); // Shallow copy of the existing array -> Re-render when new posts added
        setIsLoading(false);
      });

    /* Pd: At the first time, this function will get all the user's posts */

    return () => {
      // Detach the listening agent
      unsuscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

The FlatList

```
     <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
          legacyImplementation={false}
          numColumns={1}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}
          initialNumToRender={12}
          windowSize={40}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={15}
          updateCellsBatchingPeriod={50}
          removeClippedSubviews
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter()}
        />
```

The render item method

```
renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    const {
      images,
      dimensions,
      description,
      location,
      likes,
      comments,
      date,
    } = item;

    return (
      <View
        key={index}
        onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) => {
          this.itemHeights[index] = nativeEvent.layout.height;
        }}
      >
        <Card { /* Extends React.PureComponent */ }
          images={images}
          postDimensions={dimensions}
          description={description}
          location={location}
          likes={likes}
          comments={comments}
          date={date}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that has worked for me:

1. In render item I was passing the index as a key to the item. I have read that this can produce strange behaviour, so I decided to pass item.id (which is an UUID) instead.
2. Change the PureComponent to a Standard Component and reimplement the componentShouldUpdate life-cycle method. If you have a PureComponent it will be:

   ```
    // From the RN documentation
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return nextProps !== this.props && nextState !== this.state;
    }
   ```

So, I have decided to change my Item to a normal Component and do:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
   // My component is just a card with an author row and a progressive image (thumbnail + image) with a Skeleton absolutely positioned
   return nextState.avatarIsLoaded && nextState.thumbailIsLoaded; // && nextState.imageIsLoaded is unnecesary by the way I have implemented my component
}
```

Pd: Also it is better to do as I did because if I add the * && nextState.imageIsLoaded * I will have to wait a long time until the full image (which size is bigger than the thumbnail's one) is loaded.

Now my items render twice, firstly when the Skeleton is showed, and secondly when the progressive image is ready to being displayed.

Comment: thank you so much, I was also passing index to test what is rendered. I switched to the item.id and no more re-render of entire list.

Answer (score 1):

When your data updates, component re-renders.
To prevent that, you need to this this line before calling fetchData()

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (data) return;
    fetchData();
}, [data]);
```

*edit: add data to the dependencies array

What will happen is that the useEffect will run when the component loads, and will call fetchData function which updates your state therefore component re-renders, so the next render data will have any value so the if statement will prevent the 2nd call to fetchData.

I also suggest to initial data with null

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
```

Comment: But an empty array in useEffect doesn't indicate componentDidMount?

Comment: Using an empty array means that useEffect will run only once, because you update your state inside fetchData the component re-renders again. So the if statement is necessary to prevent the 2nd call.

Comment: Okey, that's right, thank you, but also it wouldn't be a problem here calling the function again because I update the pointer " lastLocalDataFetchedIndex" when I get an amount of images). If you see the console.logs on the terminal of Snack and go down you will see the repeated items.

Comment: That's because you increase the lastLocalData, are you trying to implement infinite scroll?

Comment: yeah, the data are just posts uploaded by users. If you see the update I did you will note that I have a listener to my DB, so I don't really call fetchData() in the useEffect. The snack was just an approach.

Comment: Will be easier to understand if you upload the full component, I don't know what is the data you use on your FlatList and also component's lifecycle

Answer (score 1):

I removed this:

```
onEndReached={fetchData}
```

and it worked fine ([see it online](https://snack.expo.io/b3ea715VN)). The problem is that react-native calls `onEndReached` when it ends rendering. so you'll get the initial datas again on each render, and it causes infinit rendering issue. ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910127/flatlist-calls-onendreached-when-its-rendered))

Comment: I have tried this but when I get the end of the FlatList not new data is rendered. In the localData array I have around 20 objects (images) which have the same uri. But the problem is not getting the same uri, the problem is that if I look the console logs the objects with the same id of other already rendered objects appears.

Comment: @Victor react will rerender the whole elements. not sure about `react-native` but in `react` that's totally normal. rendering is part of component lifecycles. but note that if it calls the render, it doesn't mean that it will re-create the items, or graphically renders them. rendering means that it process (updates) them, and if it hasn't any new changes, it wont modify the actual element. so the `console.log` is totally normal, since you did put it on render() function.

Comment: @Victor and also note that you should try to focus on issues. the first issue is infinite loading, which is solved by removing fetching datas on `onEndReached` (cause it cause it to re-render on every render.). your second issue is how to implement `onEndReached` to only get called when you reach at end of results. i'm not sure about it, lemme check the link i provided from before about `onEndReached` .

Comment: @Victor it seems that it has the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910127/flatlist-calls-onendreached-when-its-rendered react-native calls `onEndReached` on every update, as well as onscroll. so you should check if the scroll has momentium , it means it's scrolled to the und, and it's not a simple update, or something like this.