# FlatList, renderItem called multiple times on data update

Tags: reactjs, react-native, optimization, socket.io, react-native-flatlist

I'm using `Socket.io` and `FlatList` in my RN application to display a new data every 5sec (Max execution is 1min).
Every 5sec, I have a new value in my list state, and my FlatList is updated.
But it seems that the `renderItem` function of my Flatlist is called each times to rerender multiple times the results.
I tried to optimize my code with a useCallback but I think it's not efficient.
You can see my code (simplified) here :

```
export default function MyList({ navigation }) {
    const [myData, setMyData] = useState<ResponseType[]>([])

    // Socket Io
    const socket = io(SOCKET_URL, { forceNew: true, timeout: 5000 })

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("connect", () => {
            console.log("Connected to Socket ID : ", socket.id)
        })

        return () => {
            socket.disconnect()
            socket.close()
        }
    },[])

    socket.on("socketResponse", (data: ResponseType) => {
        setMyData(prevDate => [...prevDate, data])
    })

    const renderListItem = useCallback(({ item }: { item: ResponseType }) => {
        console.log(item.id)

        return (
            <TouchableOpacity key={ item.id }>
                <Text>{ item.id }</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }, [])

    return (
        <FlatList
            data={myData}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            renderItem={renderListItem}
            maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
            windowSize={2}
        />
    )
}
```

I put a `console.log` in my `renderListItem` function but with 3 elements in the list, the logs looks like this :

```
2e1f24c2-c848-44d6-98c2-3f88fc9c3fb7

2e1f24c2-c848-44d6-98c2-3f88fc9c3fb7
48355de9-b996-4e6e-bd31-abbbbca32756
2e1f24c2-c848-44d6-98c2-3f88fc9c3fb7
48355de9-b996-4e6e-bd31-abbbbca32756

2e1f24c2-c848-44d6-98c2-3f88fc9c3fb7
48355de9-b996-4e6e-bd31-abbbbca32756
21b94228-f5b9-4661-8fbf-5d813451dc31
2e1f24c2-c848-44d6-98c2-3f88fc9c3fb7
48355de9-b996-4e6e-bd31-abbbbca32756
21b94228-f5b9-4661-8fbf-5d813451dc31
```

It's like the `renderListItem` is called 2 times per new value to rerender the FlatList.
I know I need to use `PureComponent` for my items but i think that isn't the real problem here.

How Can I optimize better my `renderListItem` ?

Thanks

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63271391/react-native-flatlist-re-renders-the-already-rendered-items-when-adding-new-data

Answer (score -1):

Hi please have a look at sets in javascript. I would recommend using sets and assign id to the set key and value will be your value in that way the data will always be unique. You can read more about [sets here](https://dev.to/clairecodes/how-to-create-an-array-of-unique-values-in-javascript-using-sets-5dg6)