# React Native Check Virtualized List Render Method Error

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Im getting the error about VirtualizedList while im not using it anywhere in my entire app or even mentioning it or declaring it. Error occures ONLY WHEN I use onScroll in this flatlist. Below is my code and error exactly says this: invariant violation element type is invalid: expected a string (for built in components) but got: boolean. Check the render method of "VirtualizedList". Also I cant get on end reached to work properly no matter how much I try i think RN is buggy as hell.

```
<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <FlatList
            style={styles.feed}
            data={this.state.post}
            renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderPost(item)}
            //ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
            ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
            onScroll={this._scrolled.bind(this)}
            //onEndReached={this.retrieveMore}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter()}
            //onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}

            onEndReached={(x) => {
              this.getMore();
            }}
            //if (!onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum && !isMoreLoading)
            //{

            //}
          ></FlatList>
        </SafeAreaView>
```

My onscroll method:

```
_scrolled(){
    this.setState({ isMoreLoading: true });
  };
```

Comment: Can you post the whole error? also specify if this is a functional or class component

Comment: It is a class component, this is the error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or 
a class/function (for composite components) but got: boolean.

Check the render method of `VirtualizedList`.
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:21500:16 in <anonymous> etc

Comment: Whatever I do on end reach doesn't work I think it's bug with rn cause I was googling and others complained too so idk

Comment: The error indicates a wrong way of importing FlatList most likely, check this:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13445#issuecomment-414389398

Comment: I mean the FlatList was working for weeks and wasn't touched at all and today I added onscroll and it doesn't work so I guess it's fine with import but I'll still check ur link tnx..

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this and implement onMomentumScrollBegin on FlatList as defined [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910127/flatlist-calls-onendreached-when-its-rendered)

```
footer = () => {
    return(
     <View style={styles.headerStyle}>
       <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>This is the footer</Text>
     </View>
    );
  }

ListFooterComponent={this.footer}
```

Comment: I think the onScroll method having issues because you are changing state in that. Try removing it