# FlatList onEndReached being called multiple times

Tags: ios, react-native, reactive-programming, react-native-flatlist

I'm making a react native project where user can search images using Flickr API, Everything else is working fine but the problem i'm having while implementing pagination. I have used FlatList's `onEndReached` to detect when user has scrolled to the end on the list, but the problem is `onEndReached` is being called multiple times(including one during the first render). I have even disabled bounce as said [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14015) but it's still being called more than once

```
 export default class BrowserHome extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      tagParam: "cat",
      pageNum: -1,
      data: [],
      photosObj: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true
    });
    try {
      this.makeRequest();
    } catch {
      console.log("error has occurred");
    }
  }

  makeRequest = () => {
    const { tagParam, pageNum } = this.state;
    let url = `https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/? 
               method=flickr.photos.search
               &api_key=${apiKey}&format=json&tags=${tagParam}
               &per_page=30&page=${pageNum + 1}&nojsoncallback=1`;
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET"
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJSON => {
        this.setState({
          data: this.state.data.concat(responseJSON.photos.photo),
          isLoading: false,
          pageNum: responseJSON.photos.page
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        throw error;
      });
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return <ActivityIndicator animating={true} size="large" />;
    }

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          height: 200,
          justifyContent: "flex-start",
          width: screenSize.width,
          backgroundColor: "black"
        }}
      >
        <Text>This is browserhome</Text>
        <FlatList
          style={{
            width: screenSize.width
          }}
          numColumns={3}
          data={this.state.data}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          bounces={false}
          onEndReachedThreshold={1}
          onEndReached={({ distanceFromEnd }) => {
            this.loadMoreItem();
            alert("end reached call");
          }}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <>
              <ImageTile imageURL={this.createImageURL(item)} />
            //  <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>
             //   {index}
             //   {console.log(index)}
             // </Text>
            </>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  createImageURL(item) {
    let server = item.server,
      id = item.id,
      secret = item.secret;
    let urlString = `https://farm${
      item.farm
    }.staticflickr.com/${server}/${id}_${secret}_s.jpg`;
    return urlString;
  }

  loadMoreItem() {
    this.makeRequest();
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. Add `onMomentumScrollBegin` prop to your `FlatList` declaration.
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.data}
          onEndReached={...}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
          ...
          onMomentumScrollBegin={() => { this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = false; }}
        />

2. Modify your `onEndReached` callback to trigger data fetching only once per momentum.

  onEndReached = () => {
    if (!this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum) {
      this.props.fetchData();
      this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = true;
    }
  };
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41297034/react-native-list-view-onendreached-calling-multiple-times

Answer (score 35):

This solution worked for me. Add *onMomentumScrollBegin* and modify *onEndReached* in **FlatList** Component.

```js
<FlatList
style = { ...}
data = {data}
initialNumToRender = {10}
onEndReachedThreshold = {0.1}
onMomentumScrollBegin = {() => {this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = false;}}
onEndReached = {() => {
    if (!this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum) {
      this.retrieveMore();    // LOAD MORE DATA
      this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = true;
    }
  }
}
/>
```

Answer (score 19):

You would be best using `onEndReached` to set a boolean true, and then using `onMomentumScrollEnd` based on that.

```
onEndReached={() => this.callOnScrollEnd = true}
onMomentumScrollEnd={() => {
  this.callOnScrollEnd && this.props.onEndReached()
  this.callOnScrollEnd = false
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is how I solved my problem:

**Here is my initial state:**

```
state = {
  onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum: true,
  lastLoadCount: 0,
}
```

**This is my FlatList**

```
<FlatList
   keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
   style={...}
   data={this.state.searchResults}
   extraData={this.state}
   bounces={false}
   renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
         <SearchResultView
            uriSsource={item.image}
            itemIndex={index}
            name={item.name}
          />
   }
   showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
   keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
   numColumns={2}
   onEndReached={() => this._loadMoreData()}
   onEndReachedThreshold={0.01}
   ListFooterComponent={this._renderSearchResultsFooter}
   onMomentumScrollBegin={() => this._onMomentumScrollBegin()}
/>
```

**Here are the functions I am calling:**

```
// Key Extractor
    _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;
// Check if list has started scrolling
    _onMomentumScrollBegin = () => this.setState({ onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum: false });
// Load more data function
    _loadMoreData = () => {
            if (!this.state.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum) {
                this.setState({ onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum: true }, () => {

                    setTimeout(() => {
                        if (this.state.lastLoadCount >= 20 && this.state.notFinalLoad) {
                            this.setState({

                                page: this.state.page + 1,
                            }, () => {
                                // Then we fetch more data;
                                this._callTheAPIToFetchMoreData();
                            });
                        };
                    }, 1500);
                });
            };
        };
// Show your spinner
    _renderSearchResultsFooter = () => {
            return (
                (this.state.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum && this.state.lastLoadCount >= 20 && this.state.notFinalLoad) ?
                    <View style={{ marginBottom: 30, marginTop: -50, alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#e83628" />
                    </View> : null
            )
        }
```

Once I get data, inside of `_callTheAPIToFetchMoreData()`, I update the state like this:

```
this.setState({
  lastLoadCount: results.length,
  onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum: results.length >= 20 ? true : false,
  notFinalLoad: results.length >= 20 ? true : false
}
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 7):

The reason of triggering `onEndReached` multiple times is because you have not set `initialNumToRender` properly.

`onEndReached` is triggered in this [_maybeCallOnEndReached](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L1373) in VirtualizedList.

```
  _maybeCallOnEndReached() {
    const {
      data,
      getItemCount,
      onEndReached,
      onEndReachedThreshold,
    } = this.props;
    const {contentLength, visibleLength, offset} = this._scrollMetrics;
    const distanceFromEnd = contentLength - visibleLength - offset; 
    if (
      onEndReached &&
      this.state.last === getItemCount(data) - 1 &&
      distanceFromEnd < onEndReachedThreshold * visibleLength &&
      (this._hasDataChangedSinceEndReached ||
        this._scrollMetrics.contentLength !== this._sentEndForContentLength)
    ) {
    ...
```

if `contentLength`(the length of content rendered at once) and `visibleLength`(usually the screen height) is close, `distanceFromEnd` can be very small, thus `distanceFromEnd < onEndReachedThreshold * visibleLength` can always be `true`. By setting `initialNumToRender` and control the size of `contentLength`, you can avoid unnecessary `onEndReached` call.

Here's an example. If you render 10 items(this is the default props of `initialNumToRender`) of 70 px cells at the initial render, `contentLength` becomes 700. If the device you are using is `iPhoneX` then `visibleLength` is 724. In that case `distanceFromEnd` is 24 and this will trigger `onEndReached` unless you set `onEndReachedThreshold` less than 0.03.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set `onEndReachedThreshold` as a rate of visibleLength.
So you just need to set it as a number smaller than 1. ZERO for example or 0.5 then it  should work!!!!!

Let me know if that worked for you.

Answer (score -4):

you can disable scrolling while data receiving. in FlatList set `scrollEnabled` `false` while data loading.

```
scrollEnabled={!this.props.loadingData}
```