# onEndReached invoked multiple times on render

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

In the following little testing app onEndReached gets invoked multiple times, without me scrolling.

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([ //just a series of "random" to fill up the screen ]);
  let i = 0;
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      
      <FlatList
    inverted
    onEndReached={() => {
      let stateCopy = [...state];
      stateCopy.push("extra");
      setState(stateCopy);
    }
    }
    data={state}
    keyExtractor={item => i=i+1}
    renderItem={({ item }) => {
    return (
        <Text>{item}</Text>
    );
    }}
/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I tried doing what was described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60666252/10228836, but the solutions there didn't work. How do I fix this?

Comment: There are multiple working solutions here: [flatlist-calls-onendreached-when-its-rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910127/flatlist-calls-onendreached-when-its-rendered). Did you have a look or try them?

Comment: Nevermind, looks like setting onEndReachedThreshold to a decimal value solves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `onEndReachedThreshold={0.001}` or any other decimal number fixes the problem.