# FlatList loads data multiple times

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, infinite-scroll

I have the next simple page:

```
type Props = {
  getPostsUseCase: GetPostsUseCase
}

const renderItem = ({item}: ListRenderItemInfo<Post>) => (
  <NewsPost title={item.msg} />
)

const HomeScreen = ({getPostsUseCase}: Props) => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [shouldFetch, setShouldFetch] = useState(true)
  const [since, setSince] = useState<number | null>(null)
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<Post[]>([])

  const fetchMore = useCallback(() => setShouldFetch(since != null), [since])

  useEffect(() => {
    // Prevent fetching for other state changes
    if (!shouldFetch) return

    getPostsUseCase
      .execute({
        limit: 15,
        since: since,
      })
      .then((page: Page<Post>) => {
        setPosts(oldPosts => [...oldPosts, ...page.data])
        setSince(page.next)
      })
      .catch((error: string) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false)
        setShouldFetch(false)
      })
  }, [getPostsUseCase, shouldFetch, since])

  const onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = useRef(true)

  const onEndReachedHandler = () => {
    if (!onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum.current) {
      fetchMore()
      onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum.current = true
    }
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.frame}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          style={styles.list}
          data={posts}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
          initialNumToRender={15}
          onEndReached={onEndReachedHandler}
          onMomentumScrollBegin={() => {
            onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum.current = false
          }}
        />
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

However, it has two problems:

1. It loads two pages on start (30 items, not 15, two requests to the backend)
2. It loads entire collection multiple times on scrolling (there 30 items totally, it rendered 90)

Where is the problem? I found a lot of topics with similar problem, I tried their solutions but it didn't help (for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59732354/3253896))

I am a noobie in **React Native**. To be honest, I don't even understand my problem and their solutions, and why they don't work.

**UDP**

Finally, I came up with a working solution but there is still an annoying moment:

```
type Props = {
  getPostsUseCase: GetPostsUseCase
}

type Data = {
  posts: Post[]
  next: number | null
}

const renderItem = ({item}: ListRenderItemInfo<Post>) => (
  <NewsPost title={item.msg} />
)

const HomeScreen = ({getPostsUseCase}: Props) => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [data, setData] = useState<Data>({
    posts: [],
    next: null,
  })

  const loadData = () => {
    if (!isLoading && data.next == null) return

    getPostsUseCase
      .execute({
        limit: 15,
        since: data.next,
      })
      .then((page: Page<Post>) => {
        setData(oldPage => ({
          posts: [...oldPage.posts, ...page.data],
          next: page.next,
        }))
      })
      .catch((error: string) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false))
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  useEffect(loadData, [])

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.frame}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          style={styles.list}
          data={data?.posts}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
          onEndReached={loadData}
        />
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

**ESlint** requires to specify `loadData` in `useEffect` dependencies. I disabled that warning by `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` but it's a dirty trick...

**How to fix the solution to I was not needed disabling an ESLint rule?**

Comment: Adding the function to the useEffect array won't change anything for you and it'll satisfy the lint rule.

Comment: @Abe, unfortunately, it leads to another problem. ESLint requires to wrap `loadData` into `useCallback` that requires to specify dependencies. When I specify all required dependencies, app begins to work incorrectly loading data multiple times.